# PHP contact form needs to call Javascript to show a hidden div on main .html page

Tags: php, javascript, contact-form

I have a one page website in the works that has a contact form where its contact error and contact thank you messages are placed further down the page as hidden divs.

The contact form calls an external php file that calls the anchor links of the error and thank you message divs in the index.html file.

www.photograsurfer.com/test/index.html

www.photograsurfer.com/test/code/contact-panel.php

Everything works successfully as long as the divs are not hidden. So now I need to use the following javascript to get the hidden divs to display when needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showContactPanelError() {
document.getElementById('contact-panel-error').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

My problem, besides being a complete PHP beginner, is that I don't know how to get the PHP file to reference the Javascript code to display the hidden divs properly on the main page.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: From what I'm seeing on your page, the contact panel is sliding left and right, and having part of it stick into the page after it has been "tucked away" so to speak.

Comment: "..now I need to use the following javascript to get the hidden divs to display when needed."  When needed is a big piece of the puzzle here.  Please clarify to everyone when exactly you need it.  What triggers a contact form error?

Comment: What triggers the contact form error is if the form isnt filled out entirely, or if an invalid email is entered, etc.

Comment: What triggers the contact form thank you message is if the form is filled out correctly and the message is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a mixture of the 2 methods on these pages.

http://trevordavis.net/blog/ajax-forms-with-jquery

https://spruce.it/noise/simple-ajax-contact-form/#contact

Ditched the div idea since the Ajax method allowed me to not reload the page and enter error and thank you messages within the contact form itself. Seemed like an easier approach.

Thanks for all of the suggestions, as I never would have looked at using Ajax otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery forms (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to submit your form via AJAX, then show/hide `div`s depending on values you return from PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

you could assign php variable to javascript as

```
var error="<?php echo $_GET['error']; ?>";
```

the `$error` is the data passed along with the url like wwww.example.com/test.php?error=1

Now you could check var error and call your function showContactPanelError().

Answer (score 0):

You can add a onclick event on submit button. On clicking it will create an ajax call send data to the required external PHP file and then on success will display the hidden division properly on the main page.

here's a sample code just for an explanation

```
**
 * Description : Function that will trigger the AJAX request.
 * @param    none
 */

function CategorySubscriber_Unsubscribe(){

var data = {    
    'data-1':        data-1,
    'data-2':        data-2,
             // as per your need you can put any number of data
};


var url =  // your url

jQuery.post(url, data, function(response){
     jQuery.show("#your-div-id");
});

}
```

function(response) will be executed when ajax call will be in success status.

You can learn it from these links

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I have never used Ajax, so where would the above code go...on the main index.html file?

Comment: this has to be put in either script tag or in external js file if you have created. I recommend first go through tutorials then you will able to appreciate ajax functionality.